# Laravel : Project loading error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am very new to [laravel](http://laravel.com/) (PHP Framework).

Up to now I have downloaded test code from [HERE](https://codeload.github.com/laravel/laravel/zip/master)

Then I simply extract & put into wamp/www/ directory, but it throws error like this snap

[image]

What it is?

Help me!!

Comment: You need to use Composer to get the full Laravel package

Comment: I am also new to Composer!!!

Comment: I pasted download link of test code. Is it not full test code?

Comment: http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md If you're under Windows, look at the relative section to see how to install composer.No, it's not enought without it, you need to populate the `vendor` dir, optimise class loader, etc., all is done via the composer.json laravel file

Comment: Lets start chatting in room - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42835/room-for-napster-and-damien-pirsy

Answer (score 0):

This is because the laravel-master does not have vendor's folder in it.

Open your terminal and make sure you have php-cli installed. If not execute the following command to install php-command_line_interface, composer,git.

- sudo apt-get install php5-cli
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
- sudo apt-get install git-core

Now create new laravel project from cli that will copy fresh laravel lib in your project

- php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel /opt/lampp/htdocs/project_name

Now try to run your app. Notice that your laravel-master didn't have vendors folder. By using cli it makes sure that everything needed is installed.

Comment: I am using windows platform

Comment: Process remains the same. I have used in windows8 also. Download composer for windows, specify php.exe path where asked(usually found in c:\xampp\php\php.exe).
Once install you can use composer from command line. Type "composer create-project laravel/laravel c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project"